# How to calculate amount sum for every single product in every single quarter using linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a data table with release plans for every product: 
[image]

I'd like to calculate amount sum for every single product in every single quarter using linq. In SQL I'd use:
[image]

How can I do that in linq?
I tried this code:

```
public List<ValuePairPlanned> GetQuantityOfEachProductPlannedForRelease(int departmentId)
    {
        var amountByProducts = (from rp in _context.ReleasePlans
                                join p in _context.Products
                                    on rp.ProductProductId equals p.ProductId
                                where rp.DepartmentDepartmentId == departmentId
                                group new { rp, p } by new { rp.ProductProductId, p.ProductId, p.ProductName, rp.DateTime, rp.Amount }
       into grp
                                select new
                                {
                                    grp.Key.ProductName,
                                    grp.Key.DateTime,
                                    PlannedAmount = grp.Sum(g => g.rp.Amount)
                                }).Distinct().ToList().ConvertAll(x => new ValuePairPlanned()
                                { PlannedAmount = x.PlannedAmount, Quarter = (x.DateTime.AddDays(2).Month - 1) / 3 + 1, ProductName = x.ProductName });

        return amountByProducts;
    }
```

[image]

but as a result I get amount value for every products in every quarter. How can I fix it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `Dintinct` not work because the 'PlannedAmount' is dirrferent.

Comment: I'm sorry for this silly question but what you mean?

Comment: What type of LINQ is this? To SQL? To Entities?

Comment: Maybe to entities, cause I use Entity framework (code first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Entity Framework, look into [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) so that you can do the date addition on the SQL Server. If you do not use `DbFunctions`, then you will have to first fetch your joined tables via `ToList()` and then do the data math to calculate quarter.

The following should get you very close:

```
var amountByProducts = from p in _context.Products
             join rp in _context.ReleasePlans 
             on p.ProductId equals rp.ProductId
             where rp.DepartmentDepartmentId == departmentId
             group new
             {
                 p.ProductName,
                 Quarter = (DbFunctions.AddDays(rp.DateTime,2).Month - 1) / 3 + 1,
                 rp.Amount
             }
             // group all product plans in a given quarter
             by new
             {
                 p.ProductName, // shouldn't this be ProductId?
                 Quarter = (DbFunctions.AddDays(rp.DateTime,2).Month - 1) / 3 + 1
             }
             into grp
             // from the grouped entries, sum the amounts
             select new ValuePairPlanned()
             {
                PlannedAmount = grp.Sum(g => g.Amount),
                Quarter = grp.Key.Quarter,
                ProductName = grp.Key.ProductName
             };

return amountByProducts.ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, thats right! Thank you! Is it preferable to use DbFunctions instead calculating in query?

Comment: With your original code, you were pulling all the records down with your query (`ToList()`), doing your calculations, and then providing the rest of your program with the results.  By using `DbFunctions`, this allows you to avoid bringing any data down from the SQL server (because everything is occurring on the server) until you've calculated all the results.  It has better performance since you are transferring fewer records back from the server. In reality, this has a larger impact if you were dealing with a significant amount of records.